# R Shiny HTMLWidget for interactive 3D-histograms

Tags: r, shiny, 3d, histogram, htmlwidgets

I would like to include a 3D *dynamic* (i.e. one can change its perspective just by moving the plot) histogram widget in a R Shiny application.

Unfortunately I didn't find any until now.

So far the results of my searches: with threejs (e.g. [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/threejs/index.html) on CRAN and [there](https://bwlewis.github.io/rthreejs/) on GitHub) one can use many different representations (scatterplots, surfaces, etc.) but no **3D** histogram. plot3D and plot3Drgl don't have any R Shiny counterpart.

Unless something already exists my intention is to create an HTMLWidget from one of the sub-libraries of [vis.js](https://visjs.org/), namely [graph3d](https://visjs.org/graph3d_examples.html).

What are your views on this issue?

Best regards,

Olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My package `graph3d` is on CRAN now.

```
library(graph3d)

dat <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2), y = c(1,2,1,2), z = c(1,2,3,4))
graph3d(dat, type = "bar", zMin = 0, tooltip = TRUE)
```

You can customize the tooltips:

```
graph3d(dat, type = "bar", zMin = 0,
        tooltip = JS(c("function(xyz){",
                       "  var x = 'X: ' + xyz.x.toFixed(2);",
                       "  var y = 'Y: ' + xyz.y.toFixed(2);",
                       "  var z = 'Z: ' + xyz.z.toFixed(2);",
                       "  return  x + '<br/>' + y + '<br/>' + z;",
                       "}"))
)
```

[image]

I realize I have to add an option to control the size of the axes labels...

Comment: Wow, what a nice surprise, Stéphane! Thanks for that!
I can have a look and test your package with the data I initially thought of only at the end of next week.
I will then let you know my feedback.

Comment: Many thanks again, @Stéphane Laurent, for your work, and apologies for getting back to you much later than announced.
I finally tested your package and here is my very first feedback:

Comment: 1. The use of qualitative data on the axes (say, x and y - in my case countries and lines of business) doesn't seem to be easy/supported yet.

2. I didn't manage to assign colors to a qualitative factor (say, x - countries) with the `dataColor.fill` option.

3. I guess you didn't implement warning/error messages?

Comment: Regarding point #1 above, I guess passing a R vector to JavaScript and using the function `{x|y|z}ValueLabel` should work. But I agree an option to set the size of the axes labels would be nice^^

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with `plot3Drgl`. Here is an example.

```
library(plot3Drgl)
library(shiny)

options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rglwidgetOutput("myWebGL")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  save <- options(rgl.inShiny = TRUE)
  on.exit(options(save))
  output$myWebGL <- renderRglwidget({
    try(rgl.close())
    V <- volcano[seq(1, nrow(volcano), by = 5), 
                 seq(1, ncol(volcano), by = 5)]  # lower resolution
    hist3Drgl(z = V, col = "grey", border = "black", lighting = TRUE)
    rglwidget()
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Many thanks, Stéphane.
It works great.
Nevertheless I think an alternative with vis.js-graph3d would be useful (e.g. for tooltips, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, DSGym. I didn't know this library.

In my initial message (now amended) I actually forgot to mention the dynamic feature, i.e. the ability to change the perspective of the plot just by moving it with the mouse, like with vis.js-graph3d.

It seems plots from highcharter cannot do that, or am I mistaken?

[EDIT]: I just checked with Shiny: it is static.